# C++ lambda referencing

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Here's a bit of code I'm currently using:

```
Entity *Engine::findEntity(const std::string &name)
{
    std::for_each(p_entities.begin(), p_entities.end(),[](std::pair<const int, const std::list<Entity*>> pair) {

        std::for_each((pair.second).begin(),(pair.second).end(),[&](const Entity* &entity) {

            if ( entity->getAlive() == true && entity->getName() == name )
                return entity;
        });
    });
    return nullptr;
}
```

I'm getting the following error from intel c++:

> error : this enclosing-function local variable cannot be
>   referenced in this lambda body because an enclosing lambda does not
>   allow implicit captures

The enclosing-function local variable that the error is referring to is 'const Entity* &entity'.

If I change the lambda variable capture method from [&] to [&entity] I get the following error:

> error : identifier "entity" is undefined

I'd like to understand why this is happening and what I could do to possibly fix this.

Comment: sorry for the frequent updates, now my answer it is finally entirely correct. I have checked the code with g++. Next time, in this case preferably use iterators (to be able to break out as I also wrote).

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs No need for the apology. It's great to know that there are people like you enthusiastic to help. I've updated my question with a few other errors from the code you posted, hope you can help.

Comment: No problem, man. :) I think that should go to a separate question, as those are for new sources of errors. And as it turns out -- if I understand it correctly -- the problem is not with my code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why on earth bother with std::for_each, find_if or iterators if we have better for-each in C++11?

Coding is way shorter:

```
const Entity *Engine::findEntity(const std::string &name)
{
  for(auto& eit : p_entities)
    for(auto pe : eit.second)
      if ( pe->getAlive() == true && pe->getName() == name )
        return pe;

  return nullptr;
}
```

Just compare it to the iterator-based solution:

```
//...
#include <iterator> // do not forget this.

typedef std::map<int, const std::list<Entity*> > entity_map_t;

const Entity *Engine::findEntity(const std::string &name)
{
  using namespace std;
  const Entity* found_entity = nullptr;

  entity_map_t::iterator eit;
  for(eit=p_entities.begin(); (!found_entity) && eit!=p_entities.end(); ++eit)
  {
    list<Entity*>::const_iterator it_pEntity; // I called this originally lit. Maybe this is more expressive
    for(it_pEntity=eit->second.begin(); (!found_entity) && it_pEntity!=eit->second.end(); ++it_pEntity)
    {
      if ( (*it_pEntity)->getAlive() == true && (*it_pEntity)->getName() == name )
           found_entity = *it_pEntity;
    }
  }
  return found_entity;
}
```

Note that even iterators are much sorter than any of the lambda-approaches.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I've marked this as the answer due to its clarity. For all those interested in the details, please check Barnabas's other reply.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, you need to capture "name" in the inner and the outer lambda as well.
 Entity on the other hand must not be captured since it is a function argument.

Also, I would like to discourage you using `std::list<Entity*>>`.
Use rather `std::list<Entity*> >` because some compilers misinterpret the former as operator< and operator>>.

Corrected code so that it compiles: (`string & name` is captured by ref.)

```
Entity *Engine::findEntity(const std::string &name)
{
    using namespace std;

    for_each(p_entities.begin(), p_entities.end(),
      [&name](pair<const int, const list<Entity*>>& pair) 
      {
        for_each((pair.second).begin(),(pair.second).end(),
          [&name](const Entity* entity) 
          {
             if ( entity->getAlive() == true && entity->getName() == name )
               return entity;
          });
      });
    return nullptr;
}
```

I'll double-check this code but it should be now alright. (Except that you misplaced some further &'s: pair should be const ref, entity should just be a plain const pointer.)

SUGGESTION: To make your code a bit more readable, you could break lambda headers into the next line and you can also use in-function `using namespace std`.

UPDATE: You still have a bug in your code. `return` only returns from the lambda but the found entity never gets returned.

UPDATE2: Further correction so that the function will make a correct run:

```
// returns the last found entity.
const Entity *Engine::findEntity(const std::string &name)
{
    using namespace std;
    const Entity * found_entity=nullptr;

    for_each(p_entities.begin(), p_entities.end(),
      [&name, &found_entity](pair<const int, const list<Entity*> >& pair) 
      {
        for_each((pair.second).begin(),(pair.second).end(),
          [&name, &found_entity](const Entity* entity) 
          {
             if( entity->getAlive() == true && entity->getName() == name )
               found_entity = entity; // here you need to modify the variable captured from the outside.
          });
      });
    return found_entity;
}
```

**I would not use `for_each` in this case** though because it does not have `break` so it has to finish the loops even after it has found the Entity. I would rather use iterators here.

---

**This part is for the OP only.** This is how I filled the blanks (entire code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm> 

class Entity{

public:
  bool getAlive() const {return true;}
  std::string getName() const {return "Barna";}
};

class Engine{

public:
  const Entity *findEntity(const std::string& name);
private:
  std::map<int, const std::list<Entity*> > p_entities;
};

const Entity *Engine::findEntity(const std::string &name)
{
  using namespace std;
  const Entity* found_entity = nullptr;
  for_each(p_entities.begin(), p_entities.end(),
      [&name, &found_entity](pair<const int, const list<Entity*> >& pair) 
      { 
        for_each((pair.second).begin(),(pair.second).end(),
          [&name, &found_entity](const Entity* entity) 
          {
            if ( entity->getAlive() == true && entity->getName() == name )
               found_entity = entity;
          });
      });
  return found_entity;
}

int main()
{
  Engine e;
  e.findEntity("he");
}
```

Comment: If he's using lambdas, then c++11 is required and the >> will not be a problem.

Comment: I know, hence I wrote I only discourage it. He'll do some non c++11 work at some point and will wonder why he got the long error msg which will look like it has nothing to do with his code...

Comment: Nope because it stands out... :) But you got it! In this case, he should best use an own double-for-each-like function, for separating traversal and the work. Note that this code does not seem to do anything. Thanks, man. :)

Comment: But I think the OP thinks it should now find the entity, because of the return statement.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs Thanks for the reply. That got rid of most of the errors I was encountering. I'm getting this though after the change:  error : function "lambda [](std::pair<const int, const std::list<BasketNovel::Entity *, std::allocator<BasketNovel::Entity *>>> &)->bool::operator()" cannot be called with the given argument list. I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact I haven't declared a constant bool::operator() in my Entity class. Any ideas on how I should tackle this?

Comment: Im not sure where you have this problem. It must be in another place as I could compile the code just fine. Anyway, I'll update my answer with my test program.

Comment: @walrii Sorry, I was wrong, check my other answer, the lambdas are to be skipped entirely in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly more efficient version of Barnabas's solution:

```
// returns the first found entity.
const Entity *Engine::findEntity(const std::string &name)
{
  using namespace std;
  const Entity * found_entity=nullptr;

  find_if(p_entities.begin(), p_entities.end(),
    [&name,&found_entity](pair<const int, const list<Entity*> >& pair) 
    {
      auto it = find_if((pair.second).begin(),(pair.second).end(),
        [&name](const Entity* entity) 
        {
          if( entity->getAlive() == true && entity->getName() == name )
            return true;
          else
            return false;
        }
      );
      if (it != (pair.second).end()) {
        found_entity = *it;
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  );
  return found_entity;
}
```

note that this returns the first found entity.  If you want the last, rather than searching forwards, use `rbegin` and `rend` in place of `begin` and `end` and find the first one when searching backwards.

Comment: Thanks for the amendment. I've written the same comment to BarnabasSzabolcs, but I'm getting the following error: error : function "lambda [](std::pair<const int, const std::list<BasketNovel::Entity *, std::allocator<BasketNovel::Entity *>>> &)->bool::operator()" cannot be called with the given argument list. Would you know how I should go about tackling this?

Comment: @Yakk, it is great to see the improvement. I think, if it is a reused code, all the traversal should be put into a different, complex algorithm function, and then should come a simple lambda -- just like for comprehension and yield in python. In this situation the real deal is iterators as they are much simpler and you can more easily exit from the inner loop (say found=true and goodbye that's it ;) ). People just dig C++11 lambdas, as they look fancy, don't they? :)

Comment: @Yakk, I've posted the iterator-based approach. How do you like it?

Comment: @dk123 that would be because we guessed the type of `p_entities` to be something like `std::map<int,std::list<Entity*>>` from your original code.  If it isn't something like that, the lambda's won't work.  As an aside, don't use `std::list`, it is almost never a good idea.  By default, use `std::vector`.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs Yep, the new `for` syntax is pretty.  If only writing `iterator`s was as easy as writing a `foreach` function in more general cases in C++: I blame the lack of `yield`-like first class state as value support in C/C++.

Comment: @Yakk It seems that the new problem was due to a different piece of code. Thanks for all the help.